# Razor @Html.DropDownListFor submit & get the option value on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to submit when a dropdownlist changes by doing this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("testAction", "FishingTrip"))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Day, Model.Days,  new { onchange="this.form.submit();" })
}
```

This works fine but I am having problems (in other words don't know how) to get the option value on the server, can anybody help me with this ?

cheers 
sushiBite

Comment: can you provide the signature of your action `testAction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply have your POST controller action take it as parameter and leave the default model binder to the binding:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestAction(string day)
{
    // The day parameter will contain the selected value
    ...
}
```

Or directly use the view model you used in the view:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    // The model.Day parameter will contain the selected value
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, should have know, I'm still quite new to Razor.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `Day` property of the model parameter, like any other property / editor.